# Deploy Test Suite?

Tags: unit-test, deployment, change-set, test-suite

I just started setting up some `Test Suites`, and I certainly like the convenience they afford. However, I cannot find a way to deploy them via `Change Set`. Is it possible to deploy them in any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not look like they are available via Change Set as they are just data records in the `ApexTestSuite` and `TestSuiteMembership` tables. <strike>You will probably need to script the creation of the test suites in the target org in the same way that you would create data in Custom Settings, etc.</strike>

From the [Force.com IDE Release Notes - Spring '16 Update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_release_notes.htm):

> To create or customize a test suite, use the Developer Console or the API. [See Salesforce Help: Manage Sets of Apex Test Classes with Test Suites](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_test_suites_creating.htm) or
>
> Object Reference for Salesforce and Force.com: [ApexTestSuite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_apextestsuite.htm), [TestSuiteMembership](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_testsuitemembership.htm).

**Update:**

Upon further reading, it looks like you can query them via SOQL but you must insert the records via an API call as DML is not allowed here. **Sounds like they behave similarly to Custom Metadata records.**

> Insert a TestSuiteMembership object using an API call to associate an Apex class with an ApexTestSuite object. (ApexTestSuite and TestSuiteMembership aren’t editable through Apex DML.)
>
> To remove the class from the test suite, delete the TestSuiteMembership object. If you delete an Apex test class or test suite, all TestSuiteMembership objects that contain that class or suite are deleted.

SFDC provided SOQL Query:

```
SELECT Id FROM TestSuiteMembership 
          WHERE ApexClassId = '01pD0000000Fhy9IAC'
          AND ApexTestSuiteId = '05FD00000004CDBMA2'
```

Comment: Ah, hadn't assumed they were metadata. I guess it makes sense they would be data instead. I can't query them from the console, though. Can they be retrieved/uploaded?

Comment: I can't query for them with or without `Tooling API` selected in the query editor. Any ideas on how to move them in an automated way?

Comment: Not sure how to move them in an automated manner yet. When you say you can't query them, what was the query you used to do so? (I noticed one of the object names in the SFDC release notes quote is incorrect and updated the answer accordingly.)

Comment: I guess just `TestSuite` is giving me errors. `TestSuiteMembership` does indeed seem to have `SOQL` support. I'll see if I can data load some records. Ah, d'oh! It's `ApexTestSuite`. Figures.

Comment: The object is actually `ApexTestSuite`. You will be able to query them but in order to deploy them into your other org, what you're actually deploying are metadata objects (you might be able to subscribe to them in Eclipse), not inserting records into these queryable tables via DML.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My understanding is definitely much further along because of your efforts. The part about inserting records "using an API call" is still a bit unclear to me. Any chance you could whip up an example of how that would be done?

Answer (score 4):

ApexTestSuite is now a formal type of metadata that can be retrieved and deployed from an org. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_apextestsuite.htm

Comment: But apparently still not available in Change Sets.  (Wonder if the SF product team figures that a team with sufficient maturity to use Test Suites wouldn't be using Change Sets for change management or what)